# How to update SQL server table based on modified values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, actionscript-3

I am currently developing an AS3 module which loads content from a SQL Server Table in a data grid. Whenever the data grid is changed, the changed values should be stored in the database. My question is, Is there anyway I can accomplish this with just one SQL query?

Currently I am firing queries based on changes in each cell which is inefficient.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe add a CHANGE event listener in data grid helps.
Mark the rows updated and construct SQL queries in a batch may improve efficiency.

Comment: Can you give an example of the batch query? I am getting changes by comparing them to a back copy mode. My main concern is about queries server will execute.